# How can I make rake assets:precompile build to the right location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm deploying my Rails 3 app to a subdirectory `sapa` of my hosting service. To hit the `/sapa` subdirectory, I added a scope to `routes.rb`, but this left the application looking in `/assets` (which is not part of my app) for .js and .css instead of `/sapa/assets` (I'd have been quite happy with `assets`, but for some reason, it doesn't do that). Therefore I'm using both a `scope` statement in my `routes.rb` and a `config.assets.prefix` in my `application.rb`.

Unfortunately, this causes my `rake assets:precompile` to build into `public/sapa/assets` instead of just into `public/assets`. I can copy the files to the right location and everything works, but I'd love for someone to tell me a better way (one must exist, right?). Can I get a relative assets path (i.e. no initial `/`) or maybe a more standard way of doing what I want so that rails understands?

/config/application.rb

```
  config.assets.prefix = "/sapa/assets"
```

/config/routes.rb

```
scope "sapa" do
  …
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that by definition (see [Configuring Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets)), the `config.assets.prefix` configuration is meant to be used to defined the location from which assets are served.

```
config.assets.prefix defines the prefix where assets are served from. Defaults to /assets.
```

Could you explain, was there a reason for putting "/sapa/assets" in the `config.assets.prefix` variable? Was perhaps what you were looking for the `config.assets.paths` configuration variable?

```
config.assets.paths contains the paths which are used to look for assets. Appending paths to this configuration option will cause those paths to be used in the search for assets.
```

Comment: Thanks, @krista, but I don't think that's what I need. I fear my question was unclear and therefore I've rewritten it. I'll experiment with your suggestion tonight, but I'm pretty sure that's not what I need.